# Context-free, not-context-free, and regular grammars differentiation

Tags: context-free-grammar, dfa

Given `{a^(n+m) | n>= 2m}`, state whether it is regular, context free, or not context free and prove it using DFA, CFG, ...

My answer: it's not context free because there is no way to represent n>=2m. The greater than sign is too ambiguous.

I'm wondering if my answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is **in**correct, since a^(n+m) == a^([2m+k]+m) == a^(3m+k) where m, k >= 0. CFG representing such language is as follows:

```
 S->LR;
 R->Ra|a;
 L->LL|aaa;
```

Comment: Wouldn't the fact that you can create a CFG for it make {a^(n+m) | n>= 2m} context free?